# Stream S3 server to Cassandra

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming

Anyone please help me to how to Stream the XML files from S3 server to cassandra db using Spark Streaming java.
presently iam using Spark core to do that job..but problem is i have to to run for every 15 mints.. thats why iam looking for Spark Streaming

Comment: Though I haven't tested it but you can use Flume for Watching the updates appearing in the S3 Directory and further use [Spark-Flume Connector](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-flume-integration.html) to consume the data. You may to have write your own custom Sink and use **Pull-based Approach using a Custom Sink**.

Comment: Hello Sumit.. Thank you for your quick response....Spark Streaming is my project requirement, i cant change that.

Comment: Please open the Link provided in my comments. Spark provides elegant solution to integrate [Fume and Spark Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-flume-integration.html)